# Substitution in diophantine equation

Tags: proof-explanation, solution-verification, alternative-proof

If I have an equation $$3(1+x+x^2)(1+y+y^2)+1=4x^2y^2 $$ and I am interested in non negative integer solutions. I let $x$ be the smaller of the positive integer solution so I substitute $x+\lambda=y$ to get $$3(1+x+x^2)(1+x+\lambda+(x+\lambda)^2)+1=4x^2(x+\lambda)^2$$ I do this to apply Descartes Rule of signs to see how many non negative integer solutions exist only in terms of x. So I expand the equations and combine like terms and I know $\lambda>0$ so Descartes Rule of signs tells me only one non negative integer solution exists because theres only on change of signs. Am i right or could a change in $\lambda$ change my solution $x$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a picture of the curve in the first quadrant. There are horizontal and vertical asymptotes at $\frac{3+ \sqrt{21}}{2} \approx 3.79.$ The point where $x=y$ is at about $7.346.$ Therefore, the smaller integer coordinate can be only $4,5,6,7$ and these can be simply checked. Apparently $(4,64)$ is on the graph

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since $(4,64)$ is one solution then $4$ is one positive solution in terms of $x$. Check can $x$ have another solution with the only condition being that if we rewrite $y$ in terms of $x+ \lambda$ with $ \lambda \in \mathbb N$. If this equation had 2 non negative solutions for x with $\lambda \in \mathbb N$ then looking at the expanded equation: $$-\lambda^2 x^2 + 3 \lambda^2 x + 3 \lambda^2 - 2 \lambda x^3 + 9 \lambda x^2 + 9 \lambda x + 3 \lambda - x^4 + 6 x^3 + 9 x^2 + 6 x + 4 $$ or $$-x^4+(-2\lambda +6)x^3+\lambda(9-\lambda)x^2+(9\lambda+6+3\lambda^2)x+(4+3\lambda+3\lambda^2) $$ so it is easy to see that there is only one sign change so only one positive solution exists for x with $\lambda \in \mathbb N$

Comment: The integer root theorem implies that the rational roots must be integers also since your leading term is 1

Comment: He's been asking roughly the same question for months. Once restricted to the first quadrant or octant, there are strict bounds...I put a picture

Comment: @willjagy I am trying to extend it to many variables but dont know if I can

Comment: @argamon   I went through one of your examples in 3 variables. While slightly more complicated, the picture amounted to a three dimensional version of the picture in my answer below. That is, explicit bounds are available on the smallest variable(s). My answer below really does settle this. In brief, what you get in the first octant is a copy of $xyz=C,$ translated so that the minimum possible $x$ or $y$ or $z$ is a fixed integer larger than one.